# nginx Map $ssl_client_s_dn EMAIL address

Tags: nginx

Using Nginx I want to download from certificate information about CN, Email,  and this information sends to my application. 
But Nginx doesn't read all information: That's my configuration NGINX

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn_legacy $ssl_client_s_dn_e {
default "";
~/E=((?<E>)[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+) $E;}
```

and

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
default "";
~,CN=(?<CN>[^,Ł,ł,]+) $CN; }
```

My header

```
proxy_set_header X-Ssl-Client-S-Dn "/emailaddress=$ssl_client_s_dn_e / CN=$ssl_client_s_dn_cn"
```

CN works fine but doesn't read Polish sing 
Email does not work in this I have an empty field.

Information from application

```
Cert data from header=/emailaddress= / CN=\C5\81ukasz Str\C3\B3
```

Correct CN is Łukasz Stróż and email address lstroz@stroz.pl 
it's an example name.

Comment: You have a typo. `(?<E>)` will always capture an empty string. Remove one level of parentheses.

Comment: unfortunately Still string is empty that look my Cert info.
[Cert][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBD4p.png


and how to add polish language its some regex problem ?

Comment: You need to show what value of `$ssl_client_s_dn_legacy` and `$ssl_client_s_dn` you are trying to match against. The expression `[^,Ł,ł,]+` doesn't make sense to me. And I have already indicated that `(?<E>)` will capture an empty string.

Comment: Ok thx i fix this problem delete a polish characters from certificate